# Should I send my portfolio even after the position is no longer available?

Tags: professionalism, hiring-process, applications

I'm a copywriter.

A company I have much respect for had a vacancy three weeks ago. Because of a challenging schedule at my current job, I didn't have the time to work on my portfolio until last week. The moment I was done with the task, they wanted applicants to send them a personalized copy relevant to what they do, I found out that the position was no longer available.

As I mentioned earlier, I respect the company and their managing editor who would have been, if I had applied and been accepted, my boss. I've been a follower of his work and was hoping for a chance to work with someone I genuinely appreciate. I believe the position was a perfect fit for me.

Another important reason for feeling upset is that I'm really proud about the piece I worked on. I tackled the assignment from an uncommon angle which I think would have caught their attention.

My wife, who works in HR, recommends sending my portfolio and the piece I've worked on anyway. My counterargument: removing the vacancy from their careers page simply means they don't need copywriters for now. I shouldn't knock on the door if there's no actual need for me.

However, she told me it wasn't uncommon for companies working in the creative industry to hire worthy applicants, even with the absence of a formal opening.

Should I send the managing editor the piece I've worked on and inform him of my desire to join his team?

Comment: Where would you originally submit/send the task? If it was via some application portal then definitely your chance has passed.

Comment: Get your portfolio is order so it is ready to send out in the future.  I get this latest piece is important to you and that is great but it is just one piece.

Comment: If you don't send anything, you won't get the position. If you do send something, then the downside is that you won't get the position - but you may make a contact, and you may find a role. In short - there is no downside.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I send the managing editor the piece I've worked on and inform him of my desire to join his team?

**I see no problem in you sending those things**; usually companies keep track of any applicant or candidate for future reference, so they can perhaps call them out if future opportunities arise.

This could mean that even though they aren't currently hiring they may consider you if any position opens (*although I would not take it for granted, and look for jobs elsewhere in the meantime*).

However, sending your material regardless would *not* be recommended in case you had to submit it in some sort of portal or web page. This because the alternative way would be to directly send it to the managing editor, which can be seen as too irruptive.

Now, if he was the person you had to send those things originally I would say you send the material anyways, as in that case it would hardly be unprofessional. I would also recommend you phrase it in a way that you don't directly admit you were late to submit the material (in fact, just try not to mention it) and instead put it in a more constructive way. Perhaps something like:

> Greetings Mr. Managing Editor
>
> I am sending my portfolio and other materials as required for consideration of the job we discussed. If there is anything else you need please do tell so I can provide you with it. I hope this is still useful for you, and am looking forward to the opportunity of working with you.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. The application was supposed to go through a portal, but from what I've seen, and based on his interactions on social media channels, the managing editor seems like an approachable person who wouldn't mind an enthusiast.

Comment: @professionalism12 just enhanced my answer as you commented. Ok, in that case if you consider he is approachable I still suggest you try, just remember to keep it polite and professional. Also, look for other jobs elsewhere in case this doesn't work out.

Comment: @professionalism12 with the edits I made and the possible phrasing I included, I think you can modify it to better fit this new scenario, but in essence is should still work (perhaps expand a *little* bit on the admission that you were late, so it seems that you actually are sorry for that).